# executing Hive queries from Spark

Tags: hive, apache-spark

I'm trying to execute this code in spark-shell:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext(sc)
sqlContext.sql("show tables")
```

After executing the second line, I'm getting an exception:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getResults(Ljava/util/ArrayList;)Z
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.runHive(HiveContext.scala:305)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.runSqlHive(HiveContext.scala:272)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.NativeCommand.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(NativeCommand.scala:35)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.NativeCommand.sideEffectResult(NativeCommand.scala:35)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.execution.NativeCommand.execute(NativeCommand.scala:38)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(HiveContext.scala:360)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext$QueryExecution.toRdd(HiveContext.scala:360)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDDLike$class.$init$(SchemaRDDLike.scala:58)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.SchemaRDD.(SchemaRDD.scala:103)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext.sql(HiveContext.scala:98)
>           at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.(:14) ...

Please, help me resolve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have a version of the Hive libraries that isn't compatible with your Spark libraries.  Spark is expecting the function `org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.getResults(Ljava/util/ArrayList;)` to exist, but in your Hive libraries, it doesn't.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **spark-sql**.

To run hive queries:

> spark-sql --master yarn --num-executors 6 --executor-memory 2G
>   --executor-cores 1 --driver-memory 5G -e "select * from database.tablename;"

To run hive scripts:

> spark-sql --master yarn --num-executors 6 --executor-memory 2G
>   --executor-cores 1 --driver-memory 5G -f hivescript.hql

**Note**: Make sure hive is configured with spark installation.